# Android::how can I scale a web View?

Tags: android, view, scaling

how can I set the scaling in a web view (or any view at all)? I have a box of 200 and 200, for example. If I apply a web view to it, a web view bigger than the box, it will give me scrollbars. I am seeking for a way to scale the content in order for the webView to fit the box.

Assume that I know the dimesions of the box, and ALSO the dimensions of the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; width=device-width;"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to do this from java code. I am constructing a View and firing it to a PageBuilder class in order to build pages dynamically.